# Hide first row of result set in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

How can I hide the very first row of my tabular output in SSRS?

According to my current grouping and formatting, the first row will be always blank in  the result. So, how it is possible to hide the first row forcefully. From below image, I want to remove the first blank row only (after header).

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You can write expression on Row visibility using Rownumber()

```
=IIF(RowNumber("GroupbyCategory") > 1, True, False)
```

Comment: I am new to SSRS, Could you please have a look at the error I got. Error: "The Hidden expression for the grouping 'Group2' has a scope parameter that is not valid for an aggregate function. The scope parameter must be set to a string constant that is equal to either the name of a containing group,the name of a containing group, hte name of a containing data region, or the name of a dataset."

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the error you mentioned, change "GroupbyCategory" in Naveen Kumar's answer to your dataset name. And also change >1 to =1 if it the expression is for Hidden.

Comment: Sorry this is coming late, been off SO for a while. This works because the true part of the expression hides the rows. That means if the row number = 1, hide it. >1 will hide all other rows and leave the first row visible.